# Not able to get array using delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

On the click of a button in my `viewcontrollerA`, I'm going to `viewcontrollerB`. From `viewcontrollerB` I go to `viewcontrollerC`. And the array of images I have in `viewcontrollerC` I want to bring back to `viewcontrollerA`.

This is how I tried achieving it with delegates...

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController,ImageAssetsProtocol {

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            var vc = ViewControllerC()
            vc.delegate = self

        }

     //This below method doesn’t get called
     func sendImageAssets(myData: [MyImageAsset]) {
           print(myData)
       }

}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ViewControllerC: UIViewController {

protocol ImageAssetsProtocol {
    func sendImageAssets(myData: [MyImageAsset])
}
 weak var imagePreviewDelegate: ImagePreviewDelegate?



//ViewControllerC gets an array of images from ViewcontrollerB. I’m passing that array to ViewControllerA

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.delegate?.sendImageAssets(myData: selectedAssets)
    }

}
```

But after doing this, I don't get the array of images in ViewControllerA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can proceed:

1. Conform `VC1` to `ImageAssetsProtocol` and implement its `sendImageAssets(myData:)` method.

   ```
   class VC1: UIViewController, ImageAssetsProtocol {
       func openVC2() {
           let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as! VC3
           vc2.delegate = self
       }

       func sendImageAssets(myData: [MyImageAsset]) {
           print(myData)
       }
   }
   ```
2. In `VC2` create a `delegate` of type `ImageAssetsProtocol?` and set `vc2.delegate = self` while presenting `VC2` from `VC1`

   ```
   class VC2: UIViewController {
       var delegate: ImageAssetsProtocol?

       func openVC3() {
           let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as! VC3
           vc3.delegate = self.delegate
       }
   }
   ```
3. In `VC3` create a `delegate` of type `ImageAssetsProtocol?` and set `vc3.delegate = self` while presenting `VC3` from `VC2`. Call the delegate method `sendImageAssets(myData:)` in `viewWillDisappear(_:)`.

   ```
   class VC3: UIViewController {
       weak var delegate: ImageAssetsProtocol?

       override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
           self.delegate?.sendImageAssets(myData: selectedAssets)
       }
   }
   ```